# How does C code not Reusable and Java can have Reusable code using Inheritance?

Tags: java, c, oop, inheritance

I recently learned C. I am Confused after reading about OOPS.

The article about OOPS said the Code can be reused in Java by Inheritance concept unlike C which is Procedural Programming Paradigm. But the same can be done in C by having some Header file with all the functions that we want to reuse and Include the Head file.

My Question is what actually the "Reuse" word mean in OOPS world?

Comment: Code can be re-used in Java by Inheritance, and since C doesn't have inheritance, it cannot be re-used in that manner. But C code can be re-used in other ways. Re-use just means that you don't have to write code that is essentially the same multiple times. What is "essentially the same" can be quite subjective but at the same time, it's obvious to most in 90% of the cases.

Answer (score 4):

It's nonsense -- ignore it. There is nothing inherent about C or Java that makes code written in those languages any more or less "reusable" between projects.

The author may be making the assumption that all Java code can be made "reusable" by extending it with subclasses, and that C code cannot be "reused" because the language does not support subclasses. However, they are wrong, because:

1. This approach to "reuse" assumes that code can only ever be reused by extending, not by modifying it. This is, of course, not true.
2. Not all Java code can be usefully extended with subclasses. In fact, most Java code *cannot* be reused this way; it must be specifically architected to support this usage. (For example, a `final` class cannot be extended. Nor is it possible to extend a class consisting of a single large function without reimplementing the entire function -- at which point, nothing is actually being "reused".)